# Validar se CPF já está cadastrado API Rest NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou com uma dúvida em relação a validação de dados no NodeJS.

Eu estou aprendendo ainda eu uso sequelize para fazer minha API Rest porém estou meio travado na questão de cadastro.

Eu gostaria de saber se é possível eu validar se um determinado CPF já está cadastrado no banco de dados dentro da mesma rota e retornar uma mensagem para o Front-end. Embora eu coloque o unique no model ele não está validado e está permitindo cadastrar o cliente mesmo com o número de CPF já estando no banco de dados. As minhas consultas estão sendo todas com RAW mesmo pois acho mais fácil de fazer porque já uso em outras linguagens.

A minha rota está da seguinte forma

```
async cadastrarclientemi(req, res) {
        const {
            reqCliente,
            reqNascimento,
            reqSexo,
            reqNacionalidade,
            reqEstadoCivil,
            reqCep,
            reqEndereco,
            reqNumero,
            reqComplemento,
            reqBairro,
            reqCidade,
            reqUf,
            reqTelefone,
            reqTelefone2,
            reqTelefonefixo,
            reqEmail,
            reqProfissao,
            reqRG,
            reqCPF,
            reqPis,
            reqCtps,
            reqSerie,
            reqNomedopai,
            reqNomedamae,
            reqObservacoes,
            reqIdUsuario

        } = req.body

        const clientes = await Clientes.create({

            Cliente: reqCliente,
            Nascimento: reqNascimento,
            Sexo: reqSexo,
            Nacionalidade: reqNacionalidade,
            EstadoCivil: reqEstadoCivil,
            CEP: (reqCep.toString().match(/\d/g).join("")),
            Endereco: reqEndereco,
            Numero: reqNumero,
            Complemento: reqComplemento,
            Bairro: reqBairro,
            Cidade: reqCidade,
            UF: reqUf,
            Telefone: (reqTelefone.toString().match(/\d/g).join("")),
            Telefone2: (reqTelefone2.toString().match(/\d/g).join("")),
            TelefoneFixo: (reqTelefonefixo.toString().match(/\d/g).join("")),
            EMail: reqEmail,
            Profissao: reqProfissao,
            RG: (reqRG.toString().match(/\d/g).join("")),
            CPF: (reqCPF.toString().match(/\d/g).join("")),
            PIS: (reqPis.toString().match(/\d/g).join("")),
            CTPS: (reqCtps.toString().match(/\d/g).join("")),
            Serie: (reqSerie.toString().match(/\d/g).join("")),
            NomeDoPai: reqNomedopai,
            NomeDaMae: reqNomedamae,
            cadastradoPor: reqIdUsuario,
            Observacoes: reqObservacoes

        }).then((cliente) => {
            if (cliente) {
                res.status(201).json(cliente);

                console.log(cliente)
            } else {
                res.status(400)
                console.log("Erro ao cadastrar cliente")
            }
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
            res.status(500).json
        })
    },
```

Creio que deva ter bastante coisa incorreta ou que dê para melhorar pois estou fazendo tudo na base do Google com ajuda da documentação do sequelize.

Comment: [Não cumprimente, não agradeça, não deixe assinaturas, não use bordões, ,não use frases de efeito e não faça propaganda de seus produtos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior). [O Stack Overflow não é blog, não é forum, não é fórum e não é balcão de ajuda](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2068/137387), nós somos um [site técnico de perguntas e respostas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/137387) claras objetivas e detalhadas sobre linguagens de programação. Qualquer dúvida veja [help], [FAQ da comunidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/699/137387) e faça o nosso [tour].

Answer (score -3):

É possível sim!
Uma das formas que você pode fazer isso é construindo um método de validação dentro da tua função assíncrona cadastrarclientemi(), antes do Clientes.create().

Por exemplo:

```
let cpfAlreadyExist = reqCPF.body

if(cpfAlreadyExist) {
  await Clientes.findOne({
   where: {
    cpfAlreadyExist : reqCPF
  })
  return res.status(400).json(message: 'CPF já esta cadastrado.')
}
```

O reqCPF do ''where'' você substituiria pelo nome do campo do CPF que tá na sua model.
Existe uma forma mais fácil e mais ''clean'' de fazer uma API.

Comment: [Não cumprimente, não agradeça, não deixe assinaturas, não use bordões, ,não use frases de efeito e não faça propaganda de seus produtos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior). [O Stack Overflow não é blog, não é forum, não é fórum e não é balcão de ajuda](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2068/137387), nós somos um [site técnico de perguntas e respostas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/137387) claras objetivas e detalhadas sobre linguagens de programação. Qualquer dúvida veja [help] e [FAQ da comunidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/699/137387).